# Dynamic LSTM in Tensorflow - Optimizer Issues

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm

I have implemented the following LSTM class in Tensorflow, where the unroll operation is inspired by the dynamic_rnn() implementation within Tensorflow:

```
class LSTM():

    def __init__(self, dim_x, dim_h, batch_size):

        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.dim_x = dim_x
        self.dim_h = dim_h

        self.W_x_h = normal([dim_x, 4*dim_h])
        self.W_h_h = normal([dim_h, 4*dim_h])
        self.b_h   = zeros([4*dim_h])

        self.h_0 = zeros([batch_size, dim_h])
        self.c_0 = zeros([batch_size, dim_h])

    def lstmStep(self, x_t, h_t_minus, c_t_minus):

        lstm_mat = tf.matmul(x_t, self.W_x_h) + tf.matmul(h_t_minus, self.W_h_h) \
            + self.b_h
        i_lin, f_lin, o_lin, g_lin = tf.split(1, 4, lstm_mat)
        i_t = tf.sigmoid(i_lin); f_t = tf.sigmoid(f_lin)
        o_t = tf.sigmoid(o_lin); g_t = tf.tanh(g_lin)
        c_t = c_t_minus * f_t + i_t * g_t
        h_t = o_t * tf.tanh(c_t)

        return h_t, c_t

    def lstmUnroll(self, in_batch):

        seq_len = array_ops.shape(in_batch)[0]
        in_batch_ta = tensor_array_ops.TensorArray(dtype = in_batch.dtype, size = seq_len)
        in_batch_ta = in_batch_ta.unpack(in_batch)
        h_arr = tensor_array_ops.TensorArray(dtype = in_batch.dtype, size = seq_len)
        time = array_ops.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32)
        inputs_got_shape = in_batch.get_shape().with_rank(3)
        (const_time_steps, const_batch_size, const_depth) = inputs_got_shape.as_list()

        def compute(time, h_t, c_t, h_arr_t):
            x_t = in_batch_ta.read(time)
            h_t, c_t = self.lstmStep(x_t, h_t, c_t)
            h_arr_t = h_arr_t.write(time, h_t)
            return [time+1, h_t, c_t, h_arr_t]

        (_1, _2, _3, h_arr) = control_flow_ops.While(
            cond=lambda time, _1, _2, _3: time < seq_len,
            body=compute,
            loop_vars=(time, self.h_0, self.c_0, h_arr),
            parallel_iterations=32)

        output = h_arr.pack()

        return output
```

I define a graph using the LSTM with some cost function. The graph compiles properly, and I'm able to forward propagate using 'in_batch' which is of size [sequence_length, batch_size, input_dim]. 'sequence_length' can vary for different batches. However, when I use an optimizer(Adam) with the cost function, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "textToImage.py", line 351, in <module>
    opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(temp)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 192, in minimize
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 297, in apply_gradients
    update_ops.append(self._apply_dense(grad, var))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/adam.py", line 129, in _apply_dense
    self._epsilon_t, grad, use_locking=self._use_locking).op
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/gen_training_ops.py", line 81, in apply_adam
    use_locking=use_locking, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 655, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2042, in create_op
    set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1528, in set_shapes_for_outputs
    shapes = shape_func(op)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/training_ops.py", line 72, in _ApplyAdamShape
    grad_shape = op.inputs[9].get_shape().merge_with(v_shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 541, in merge_with
    self.assert_same_rank(other)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 584, in assert_same_rank
    "Shapes %s and %s must have the same rank" % (self, other))
ValueError: Shapes () and (1000, 512) must have the same rank
```

Here 1000 is 'dim_x' and 512 is 4*'dim_h', so the error is for 'W_x_h'. I have tried using '.set_shape()' for 'x_t', 'h_t', 'c_t' and 'output' in 'lstmUnroll()', still fails.

Any ideas to make it work with the optimizer?

Comment: What's the `temp` tensor that you pass to `minimize()`, and does it have shape `(1000, 512)`?

Comment: No, 'temp' is the cost function that I defined. Unfortunately, the code is quite big, so I couldn't post the whole thing here.

Comment: I upgraded to the latest build [here](http://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-matrix-cpu/TF_BUILD_CONTAINER_TYPE=CPU,TF_BUILD_IS_OPT=OPT,TF_BUILD_IS_PIP=PIP,TF_BUILD_PYTHON_VERSION=PYTHON2,label=cpu-slave/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/pip_test/whl/tensorflow-0.7.1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl). Surprisingly, the code now works without changing anything. Probably some updates in control_ops because of scan.